# Jquery knockout dynamic template not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js, knockout-2.0

I have a view model:

```
function ViewModel() {
    this.applications = ko.observableArray();
    this.templateView = ko.observable("application-grid");
    this.templateToUse = function () {
        return this.templateView();
    }.bind(this);
};
var viewModel = new ViewModel();
ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

I have a list that is binded to the viewModel

```
<ul data-bind="template: { name: templateToUse, foreach: applications }"></ul>
```

When the page loads, it firs selects the "application-grid" template id.

When i change it first time, `viewModel.templateView('application-list');`, the template changes.

Then, if i change it back, `viewModel.templateView('application-grid');`, the template doesn't change anymore.

I am doing something wrong?

Comment: Your code should work fine... http://jsfiddle.net/K9LVY/

Comment: I see, i will debug the code to see what is creating this problem

Comment: @nemesv: I found the problem. It seems that jquery.tmpl creates a conflict with knockout. I need to find a solution for this because i need both scripts

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use knockout templates then you can specify that in bindings:

```
<ul data-bind="template: { name: templateToUse, foreach: applications, templateEngine: new ko.nativeTemplateEngine() }"></ul>
```

by default knockout will use jquery templates if it is referenced on page. You could also use other templates, for more info see [documentation](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/template-binding.html).